# Use the same constant buffer in distinct shaders

Tags: c++, directx, shader, hlsl

I have two distinct shaders (PS and VS as separate files) and in both of them I need to use exactly the same constant buffer.
Do they share this constant buffer or has the code to be doubled?

I'm not using Effects so I have to compile PS and VS shaders separately in different files using Visual Studio if I want to compile shaders at build time instead of runtime (so CompileFromFile is not the case for me).

Here's my approach right now, which obviously gives me render mistakes:

VertexShader:

```
cbuffer cbPerObject : register(b0)
{
    float4x4 gWorld;
    float4x4 gWorldInvTranspose;
    float4x4 gWorldViewProj;
    Material gMaterial;
};
```

PixelShader:

```
cbuffer cbPerObject : register(b0)
{
    float4x4 gWorld;
    float4x4 gWorldInvTranspose;
    float4x4 gWorldViewProj;
    Material gMaterial;
};

cbuffer cbPerFrame : register(b1)
{
    DirectionalLight gDirLight;
    PointLight gPointLight;
    SpotLight gSpotLight;
    float3 gEyePosW;
};
```

The way I set constant buffer in my Render() method (I have a single object right now so perObj and perFrame buffers are set in the same way):

```
m_d3dContext->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, m_cBuffer_perObject.GetAddressOf());
m_d3dContext->PSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, m_cBuffer_perObject.GetAddressOf());
m_d3dContext->PSSetConstantBuffers(1, 1, m_cBuffer_perFrame.GetAddressOf());
```

So what does not work? I have a simple cube mesh. I successfully rendered cube for vertexPos + vertexColour input layout and this time I tried to add some lighting formulae so I amde new input layout with vertexPos + vertexNormal

```
    { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
    { "NORMAL", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 0, D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 }
```

As a result instead of my cube I have something extremely huge rendered (scales are not the problem so as the camera because again, I used same scale and camera for the same cube for colour blending and lighting formulae are taken from book and can't cause mistakes).

Comment: How are Material , DirectionalLight, PointLight and SpotLight defined? Maybe you have alignment problems.

Comment: @VuVirt alignment are considered and paddings are used for proper alignment. Also did a small test and it seems colours are displayed properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working: I simply forgot to consider packing differences between hlsl and c++.
If someone is interested in solution, I had to add this single pre-processor command to my hlsl code:

```
#pragma pack_matrix(row_major)
```

(or send transposed matrices to constant buffer)